# Show that an estimator has a lower variance than another estimator

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X $ be observed data. Let $\hat{\theta}(X)$ be an unbiased
estimate of $\theta$ and let T be a sufficient statistic for $\theta$. Define the new estimator 
$\hat\theta^{*}$ of $\theta$,

$$ \hat\theta^{*}(X) =E(\hat\theta(X)| T)
$$

Then, show that:

- $\hat\theta^{*}(X)$ has a variance that is lower than (or equal to) that of $ \hat\theta$

Hint: for any two random variables $X$ and $Y$, $\operatorname{VAR}(X)= E(\operatorname{VAR}[X|Y]) +VAR[E(X|Y)]$ and $E(E(X|Y)=E(X)$

Comment: Strings like `VAR` are interpreted as concatenated variables and thus get italicized. To get the right font and spacing for such function names, you can either use predefined commands like `\sin`, or generally `\operatorname{name}` to produce $\operatorname{name}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $\mathrm{Var}(E(\hat{\theta}|T))$ $=\mathrm{Var}(\hat{\theta})-E(\mathrm{Var}(\hat{\theta}|T))$.
Since $\mathrm{Var}(\hat{\theta}|T)$ is a non-negative random variable, its expected value is also non-negative. So, we have that $\mathrm{Var}(\hat{\theta}^{*})=\mathrm{Var}(E(\hat{\theta}|T))$ $\leq \mathrm{Var}(\hat{\theta})$

Comment: There's a preview window underneath the answer field. If it's not working for you, it might be worthwhile to post a bug report at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com (stating your browser version).

Comment: Also, see my comment under the question regarding the formatting of $\operatorname{Var}$.